# Alternative to Sqlite for iPhone [monotouch]

Tags: iphone, sqlite, xamarin.ios

Like the title says.

I find a lot of the issues I have are related to the lack of thread safety in the Sqlite wrapper needed for using Sqlite with Monotouch - so - the question is - is there an alternative? There must be *something*!!?

w://

Comment: Sorry, originally posted an answer, but didn't realize monotouch is hating on coredata.  Only information I could find was: http://forums.monotouch.net/yaf_postst156_Data-persistence-with-Monotouch.aspx

Comment: The sqlite dynlib that comes with the iPhoneSDK is not threadsafe, but you could compile your own static sqlite library from the source with the threadsafe macro turned on. See http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sqlite itself is not thread safe, so you need to manually take a lock whenever you are going to access the database.   You can see how I did this with TweetStation:

http://github.com/migueldeicaza/TweetStation/

This allows me to update the database in the background.

There are a couple of bindings to Sqlite: sqlite-net which is a tiny Sqlite binding or Mono.Data.Sqlite.

As for CoreData, it would have the same problems, you do not get thread safety for free, you need to follow their rules as well.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 4, you can call sqlite3_config( SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED ), or using Sqlite3 wrapper in C#:

```
    var result = SQLite3.Config(SQLite3.ConfigOption.Serialized);
    if (result != SQLite3.Result.OK)
    {
        throw new InvalidProgramException("sqlite3 refused Serialized option");
    }
```

Comment: Where is the SQLite3 namespace in?